# How to implement hardware device registration to a Django user account

Tags: python, django, registration, django-allauth

I am currently working on a website that will allow the user to interact with a hardware unit they can setup in their home. I am currently doing my user registration using django-allauth and this works as desired. My next step is to allow the user to link their hardware unit to their account. I hope to implement this using some sort of unique key made up of characters (e.g. Sr3D-$3tr-SQ2Q-CB24) that can only be linked to a single account. I don't want this to be part of the User model (for registration), rather something they can link later on in say a Profile model (linked to the User model).

I have searched extensively for django packages or examples that implement similar functionality however have had no luck. I believe this to be pretty standard functionality, for example when you have to register a game you buy (to access online functionality) using the key-phrase that comes with your purchase.

Can anybody point me to some examples or packages of how this would be implemented using Django?

[EDIT] 
After BingsF's first answer below I thought I should be more precise in the functionality I am after. Basically I would like to have a table in a database where I could add legitimate keys along with the username of the user who registers it (initially 'Null' until a User registers themselves with the key). Then when the user registers I would want a check to ensure they have entered a legitimate key and it hasn't been registered before.

A user should be able to register multiple devices.

Comment: how many keys per user ?

Comment: The implementation I am aiming for would allow the user to register as many devices as they like (that they purchase). Therefore technically an unlimited number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would probably be to create a new Model, with a foreign key referencing the User model.

It would look something like this (in your models.py):

```
class Device(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    hardware_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
```

Then, on your webpage, when a user uploads a new hardware key you would do:

```
from models import Device, User

try:
    device = Device.objects.get(hardware_key=<key>)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # deal with case where user tries to register non-existent key
else:
    try:
        device.username = <user>
        device.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        # deal with case where key is already registered to another user
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/) for more info on creating/using models

Comment: I figured I would have to take this approach if there was no packages available to handle this for me.

Two points:

1. I would like to have a table in a database where I could add legitimate keys along with the username of the user who registers it (initially 'Null' obviously). Then when the user registers I would want a check to ensure they have entered a legitimate key and it hasn't been registered before. Should I make some sort of 'Device' model to handle this functionality?

2. It seems a bad design to me to have to make multiple profiles for each key a User registers?

Comment: 1. Using the table as-is, with Null as the user initially seems like a good choice. To check that the key has not been registered before, just check whether the row for that key contains Null or another user. To enforce one-user-per-key, set primary_key=True as a parameter in hardware_key (changed above).
2. That's true, perhaps the table should be called "Device" then, and have a "Profile" table for the other stuff associated with their user account. Having just the two columns in the table then makes a properly-designed One-To-Many relationship between User and the hardware key.